# How to extract product name from statement using RASA?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, nlu

I am beginner in RASA. I want to extract the product name as entity from a statement like "Add X to cart", "Select X" or "Put X in cart". My bot is identifying the intent correctly but is unable to extract the entity. It is only able to pick entities very close to what I put in examples. What I want is to detect anything that is put in the statement as an entity. How can I do this?

I tried regex example like [A-Za-z0-9]+ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure a [RegexEntityExtractor](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components/#regexentityextractor) in your pipeline? You'll likely want to add something like this to your `config.yml` file.

```yaml
  - name: RegexEntityExtractor
    case_sensitive: False
    use_lookup_tables: True
    use_regexes: True
```

The regexes should be available in a [lookup table](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu-training-data#lookup-tables). This is part of your `nlu.yml` file. Here's the example from the docs:

```yaml
nlu:
- lookup: country
  examples: |
    - Afghanistan
    - Albania
    - ...
    - Zambia
    - Zimbabwe
```

You should be able to add regexes here.